# Statusbar padding even when hidden (flutter)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make an immersive view, where nothing is over the widget.

But even with `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive)`, the status bar still takes a place where it used to be.

For a test widget, this is what I used

`return Container(color: Colors.red);`

That is the entire widget, yet it still has a status bar padding

[image]

When I use a Scaffold, I can draw behind the Status Bar, but when there is no Status Bar, it still takes up the extra space.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently using

`<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>`

In `styles.xml` fixed it, because my emulator had a simulated cutout

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
void main() {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

You can also make it transparent

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, ));
```

Comment: 1- That method is deprecated. 2- It has the same effect as going immersive, so it doesn't solve anything

Answer (score 0):

Go to android\app\src\main\res\values. Open styles.xml and below this:

```
     This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
```

Add this:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

Now status bar behaves like in a game: no status bar, but if you swipe down - the status bar is appearing
Also, there is no padding even if the device screen has cutout.